# How to send byte array with image from AS3 to PHP?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, air, arrays

I have from AS3 AIR App to send an image, beside rest of POST parameters to the PHP script which will do the rest. I want to somehow convert byte array with image to string and encode it with base64. I was successfull, but image data is wrong.

Here is the code I used to convert it:

```
...
//BA1 is Byte Array with an image in it
var data:String = BA1.toString();
OutSql.push({t: "b1", v: Base64.encode(data)});
...
```

Everything works fine, this data is sent to server, decoded, and stored as an image, but image is wrong. Somehow it is about 40 kb, while when I save it within Air application it is 22 kb. Any ideas?

p.s. I know that I can save it localy and upload it, but I really need to do it this way. Also, BA1.readUTF() generates an error, so not an option.

**Addition**:

On a server side I have tried to utf8_decode string before writing to file, and somehow I got an image which is proper dimensions, but... that image is not what I wanted to be, it looks like scribble...

Comment: Does `BA1` contain data of jpeg or png or just raw bitmapData (used `getPixels();` for bytes)? If its already jpg/png then use `Base64.encode(BA1)` then the B64 itself will give you an encoded string from the bytes. Anyway your size is 40kb (from 22kb) cos you used `toString`. Consider two bytes **0xFF** and **0xD8** (total size is 2) now as a string it is **FFD8** which is total size 4. The conversion is doubling the size. If possible just do a `trace ("bytes are : " + BA1);` then show me here the first 8 letters of the BA1 bytes. Easier to assess the format that way...

Comment: BA1 contains jpeg data. However, trying to encode BA1 generates an error, cause only string can be encoded, not a byte array.

Comment: Here is answer for trace:
`bytes are : ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛ`
which looks like a good jpeg header. But the rest of data is just messed up. Image siye is correct, by the way.

Comment: Why not send the image as binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import com.sociodox.utils.Base64;
.....
//BA1 is ByteArray with an image encoded
var enc_image=Base64.encode(BA1);
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("some.php");
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.decode("image="+enc_image);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = variables;
loader.load(request);
```

of course, set your listeners, too...

in "some.php":

```
$imageData = base64_decode(str_replace(" ", "+", $_POST['image']));
$fh = fopen("path/to/image/somename.jpg", "wb");
fwrite($fh, $imageData);
fclose($fh);
```

This works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Soultion found. I have downloaded from http://www.sociodox.com/base64.html Base64.swc which is actually encoding and decoding image Byte Arrays. And because my string was JSON-ed (as a part of object sent to PHP) I had only to convert spaces to '+' and decode it and write to file - works perfect! Case closed.